# By using AspectJ, how can I get 'Object' reference created by 'new' keyword?

Tags: java, aspectj, aop

Let me directly jump into the example.

```
public class Target {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Target target = new Target();
        Target target2 = new Target();
    }
}
```

I try to capture the Object references(*.hashCode()) by using AspectJ. I prepared code like below:

```
public aspect ObjectCreationAspect {
    before() : initialization(*.new(..)) && !within(ObjectCreationAspect) {
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

I know 'initialization' captures 'new' keyword, but I don't know how can I get the Object itself created by this 'new' keyword. I tried some 'get' methods but they just get only plain name, type(not object), and so forth. What I want is printing values same with target.hashCode() and target1.hashCode() inside this Aspect.

Please give me some hints.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer.

```
thisJoinPoint.getTarget().hashCode()
```

This code will return the reference of newly created object.